# How do I enable chacha/poly in openssl1.1.0

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I was looking to enable chacha/poly algorithm in the openssl 1.1.0 version. I googled alot but couldn't get the resolution. please help me if any one knows

Answer (score 1):

> How do I enable chacha/poly in openssl1.1.0

ChaCha20/Poly1305 is enabled by default in OpenSSL 1.1.0. With all other things being equal, you will use it if its a common cipher and its selected by the client or server.

If you are not seeing ChaCha20/Poly1305 as the cipher suite, then check the server. It probably lacks support for curve25519 or the cipher suite. You should still see the cipher suite advertised in the ClientHello.

A disappointing thing about ChaCha and Poly1305 is they are only available as a unit via `EVP_chacha20_poly1305`. You cannot use just ChaCha or just Poly1305. (And ChaCha is TLS's ChaCha, and not Bernstein's ChaCha).

Also see [How to use Poly1305 with EVP interfaces?](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2016-November/004894.html) on the OpenSSL Users mailing list.